# Hangman game code

Tags: java, hangman

I've developed a code for a Hangman game and what I need help in is basically simplifying, correcting and removing parts of the code that are not needed (or there is an easier way to do it). I think there are parts where I could have done it easier but I do not know where they are. I would appreciate any/ all help and will welcome all constructive criticism.

```
package Hangman;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.net.URL;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HangManGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    // Panels where everything is drawn on
    DrwPnl dPnl1 = new DrwPnl(), dPnl2 = new DrwPnl(), pnlBoard = new DrwPnl();

    JPanel align = new JPanel(), pnl2 = new JPanel(), pnl3 = new JPanel(),
            pnl4 = new JPanel(), pnl5 = new JPanel(), pnl6 = new JPanel(),
            pnl7 = new JPanel();

    String p1 = "Dixon", p2 = "Computer", puz = "", selected = "Easy";
    String[] categories = { "Easy", "Food", "Standard", "Geography", "Hard",
            "Holidays", "Animals", "Sports" }, allPuz, puzzle;

    JTextField cusPuz = new JTextField("Custom Puzzle"),
            txtName = new JTextField("Player"), txtOpponent = new JTextField(
                    "Opponent");

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel(), lblOpponent = new JLabel(),
            wordlist = new JLabel();

    JButton[] btnLetters = new JButton[26], close = new JButton[3],
            lblWordList = new JButton[8];
    JButton player1 = new JButton(), player2 = new JButton(),
            btnBack = new JButton("Back"), btnStart = new JButton("Start"),
            resetBtn = new JButton("Reset Scores"), newGameBtn = new JButton(
                    "New Game"), btnMain = new JButton("Menu");

    int length, count = 0, chances = 7, linenum, randomnum, pScore = 0,
            oScore = 0, theSource = 1, move = 0, rong, players = 1;
    int[] wrLetter = new int[26], checked = new int[26];

    Icon[] cate = new ImageIcon[7];
    Icon py1 = new ImageIcon("Player 1.png"), py2 = new ImageIcon(
            "Player 2.png"), wList = new ImageIcon("WordList.png"),
            name = new ImageIcon("Name.png"), opponent = new ImageIcon(
                    "Opponent.png"), closeIMG = new ImageIcon("closeBtn.png");

    char[] puzle, hid, leter = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
            'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' }, leter2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
            'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    Boolean wrong = true, undecorated, gameDone = false;

    JFrame fr1 = new JFrame(""), fr2 = new JFrame("");

    // Import Font File----------------------->
    File f = new File("VTK.ttf");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    Font dFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
    Font f1 = dFont.deriveFont(12f), f2 = dFont.deriveFont(11f), f3 = dFont
            .deriveFont(12f), f4 = dFont.deriveFont(50f), f5 = dFont
            .deriveFont(16f), f6 = dFont.deriveFont(13f), f7 = dFont
            .deriveFont(35f), f8 = dFont.deriveFont(22f);
    // <----------------------- End Import Font File

    // Import Images----------------------->
    ClassLoader cl = HangManGUI.class.getClassLoader();
    URL imageURL = cl.getResource("chalkBG.png"), imageURL2 = cl
            .getResource("hanger.png"), imageURL3 = cl
            .getResource("alphaDock.png");
    Image image, image2, image3;
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    // <----------------------- End Import Images

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HangManGUI();
    }

    public HangManGUI() throws Exception {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        // Initialize the Checklists------------->
        for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
            checked[x] = 0;
            wrLetter[x] = 0;
        }
        // <------- End Initializing Checklists

        // Close button--------------------------->
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            close[x] = new JButton();
            close[x].addActionListener(this);
            close[x].setOpaque(false);
            close[x].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            close[x].setBorderPainted(false);
            close[x].setBounds(275, 0, 25, 25);
            close[x].setIcon(closeIMG);
        }
        dPnl1.add(close[0]);// Add Close button to 1st Screen
        dPnl2.add(close[1]);// Add Close button to 2nd Screen
        this.add(close[2]);// Add Close button to Board
        close[2].setBounds(475, 0, 25, 25);
        // <------End Close Button

        // Put image into Image Variable------------->
        if (imageURL != null) {
            image = toolkit.createImage(imageURL);
            image2 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL2);
            image3 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL3);
        }
        // <-------------Put image into Image Variable

        // ////Chose Player Menu(1)==============>
        dPnl1.setLayout(null);
        // /Player 1 button initialize--------->
        player1.setBounds(25, 125, 250, 50);
        player1.setOpaque(false);
        player1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        player1.setBorderPainted(false);
        player1.addActionListener(this);
        player1.setIcon(py1);
        dPnl1.add(player1);
        // /Player 2 button initialize--------->
        player2.setBounds(25, 200, 250, 50);
        player2.setOpaque(false);
        player2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        player2.setBorderPainted(false);
        player2.addActionListener(this);
        player2.setIcon(py2);
        dPnl1.add(player2);
        // /End Player Button Initialzing------->
        fr1.add(dPnl1);
        fr1.setUndecorated(true);// Take out preset border
        undecorated = fr1.isUndecorated();// Take out preset border
        fr1.setVisible(true);
        fr1.setSize(300, 300);
        fr1.setLocation(300, 300);
        // ////<========End Chose Player Menu(1)

        // ////Chose Categories Menu(2)========>
        dPnl2.setLayout(null);
        // /Initialize WordList Icon\Label--->
        dPnl2.add(wordlist);
        wordlist.setBounds(100, 75, 150, 75);
        wordlist.setIcon(wList);
        // /Initialize Go To 1st Menu Button---------->
        dPnl2.add(btnBack);
        btnBack.setBounds(0, 250, 75, 25);
        btnBack.setFont(f2);
        btnBack.addActionListener(this);
        btnBack.setOpaque(false);
        btnBack.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnBack.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnBack.addActionListener(this);
        // /Initialize Start Game/Go to Board---------->
        dPnl2.add(btnStart);
        btnStart.setBounds(225, 250, 75, 25);
        btnStart.setFont(f2);
        btnStart.addActionListener(this);
        btnStart.setOpaque(false);
        btnStart.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnStart.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnStart.addActionListener(this);
        // /Add Categories into grid------------->
        align.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            lblWordList[x] = new JButton(categories[x] + "");
            lblWordList[x].setFont(f3);
            lblWordList[x].setOpaque(false);
            lblWordList[x].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            lblWordList[x].setBorderPainted(false);
            lblWordList[x].addActionListener(this);
            align.add(lblWordList[x]);
        }
        // /<-------------End Category Initializing and Layout Setiing
        fr2.add(dPnl2);
        fr2.setSize(300, 300);
        fr2.setLocation(300, 300);
        fr2.setUndecorated(true);// Take out preset border
        undecorated = fr2.isUndecorated();// Take out preset border
        // ////<==================End Chose Player Menu(2)

        // ////Create Playing Board================>
        // Add Board to main form------------->
        pnlBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        pnl2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnl2.add(pnlBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // <---------End Add Board to main form
        pnl7.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        pnl7.add(pnl2);
        // Initialize New Game Button---------->
        newGameBtn.setFont(f2);
        newGameBtn.addActionListener(this);
        newGameBtn.setFocusable(false);
        newGameBtn.setOpaque(false);
        newGameBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        newGameBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.add(newGameBtn);
        newGameBtn.setBounds(225, 0, 100, 25);
        // Initialize Reset Scores Button---------->
        resetBtn.setFont(f2);
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn.setFocusable(false);
        resetBtn.setOpaque(false);
        resetBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        resetBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.add(resetBtn);
        resetBtn.setBounds(100, 0, 125, 25);
        // Initialize Go To Main Menu Button---------->
        btnMain.setFont(f2);
        btnMain.addActionListener(this);
        btnMain.setFocusable(false);
        btnMain.setOpaque(false);
        btnMain.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnMain.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.add(btnMain);
        btnMain.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 25);

        this.add(pnl7);
        this.setUndecorated(true);// Take out preset border
        undecorated = this.isUndecorated();// Take out preset border
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.setSize(500, 325);
        // ////<===========End Create Playing Board
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == player1) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 was pressed");
            fr1.setVisible(false);
            fr2.setVisible(true);
            theSource = 2;
            players = 1;
            lblWordList[1].setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            dPnl2.add(align);
            align.setBounds(25, 125, 250, 100);
            align.setOpaque(false);

            dPnl2.add(lblName);
            lblName.setBounds(50, 50, 75, 25);
            lblName.setFont(f2);
            lblName.setIcon(name);

            dPnl2.add(txtName);
            txtName.setBounds(125, 50, 125, 25);
            txtName.setFont(f6);
            txtName.setOpaque(false);
            txtName.setBorder(null);

            dPnl2.add(wordlist);
            wordlist.setBounds(100, 75, 150, 75);

            dPnl2.remove(lblOpponent);
            dPnl2.remove(txtOpponent);
            dPnl2.remove(cusPuz);
        } else if (e.getSource() == player2) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 was pressed");
            lblWordList[1].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            players = 2;
            theSource = 2;
            selected = "Custom";
            fr1.setVisible(false);
            fr2.setVisible(true);
            dPnl2.remove(align);

            dPnl2.remove(wordlist);
            dPnl2.add(lblOpponent);

            lblOpponent.setBounds(75, 125, 100, 25);
            lblOpponent.setFont(f2);
            lblOpponent.setIcon(opponent);

            dPnl2.add(txtOpponent);
            txtOpponent.setBounds(175, 125, 100, 25);
            txtOpponent.setFont(f6);
            txtOpponent.setOpaque(false);
            txtOpponent.setBorder(null);

            dPnl2.add(cusPuz);
            cusPuz.setBounds(100, 175, 100, 25);

            dPnl2.add(lblName);
            lblName.setBounds(75, 75, 75, 25);
            lblName.setFont(f2);
            lblName.setIcon(name);

            dPnl2.add(txtName);
            txtName.setBounds(150, 75, 125, 25);
            txtName.setFont(f6);
            txtName.setOpaque(false);
            txtName.setBorder(null);

        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnBack) {
            theSource = 1;
            System.out.println("Back was pressed");
            fr2.setVisible(false);
            fr1.setVisible(true);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            lblWordList[x].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            if (e.getSource() == lblWordList[x]) {
                if (players == 1) {
                    selected = lblWordList[x].getText();
                    lblWordList[x].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    System.out.println(x);
                } else
                    selected = p2 + "'s Puzzle";
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnStart) {
            theSource = 3;
            System.out.println("Start was pressed");
            p1 = txtName.getText();
            if (players == 2)
                p2 = txtOpponent.getText();
            fr2.setVisible(false);
            try {
                if (players == 1)
                    getPuz();
                createPuz();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                System.out.println("Problem Creating Puzzle");
            }
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            if (e.getSource() == close[x]) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == resetBtn) {
            oScore = 0;
            pScore = 0;
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == newGameBtn) {
            imageURL2 = cl.getResource("hanger.png");
            image2 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL2);
            move = 0;
            count = 0;
            gameDone = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                checked[x] = 0;
                wrLetter[x] = 0;
            }
            try {
                getPuz();
                createPuz();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                System.out.println("Problem Creating Puzzle");
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnMain) {
            oScore = 0;
            pScore = 0;
            move = 0;
            count = 0;
            gameDone = false;
            p2 = "Opponent";
            p1 = "Player";
            for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                checked[x] = 0;
                wrLetter[x] = 0;
            }
            this.setVisible(false);
            fr2.setVisible(true);
            theSource = 2;
        }
    }

    class DrwPnl extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            if ((theSource == 1) || (theSource == 2)) {
                g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300, this);
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2.setFont(f4);
                if (theSource == 1)
                    g2.drawString("Hang Man", 12, 100);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if (theSource == 3) {
                g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 275, 0, 0, 300, 300, this);
                if ((move < 5) && (move >= 0))
                    g2.drawImage(image2, 300 - 25 * move, 125, 350 - 25 * move,
                            200, 0, 0, 131, 300, this);
                if ((move >= 5) && (move < 7))
                    g2.drawImage(image2, 300 - 25 * move, 100, 350 - 25 * move,
                            175, 0, 0, 131, 300, this);
                if ((move == 7) || (move >= 8)) {
                    g2.drawImage(image2, 125, 50, 175, 150, 0, 0, 131, 300,
                            this);
                    if (move == 7) {
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.fillRect(125, 150, 50, 25);
                    }
                }
                g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2.drawLine(365, 25, 365, 215);
                g2.drawLine(25, 210, 375, 210);
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2.fillRect(50, 175, 125, 25);
                g2.fillRect(75, 25, 25, 150);
                g2.fillRect(100, 25, 75, 25);
                g2.fillRect(175, 175, 25, 25);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2.drawLine(100, 75, 125, 50);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.setFont(f8);
                g2.drawImage(image3, 0, 275, 500, 325, 0, 0, 320, 48, this);
                for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                    if (wrLetter[x] == 0)
                        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    else if (wrLetter[x] == 1)
                        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    else if (wrLetter[x] == 2)
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2.drawString("" + leter[x], 5 + 19 * x, 305);
                }
                g2.setFont(f7);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
                    g2.drawString("" + hid[x], 25 + 35 * x, 250);
                g2.setFont(f5);
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2.drawString("Category:", 375, 50);
                g2.drawString(p1, 375, 100);
                g2.drawString(p2, 375, 150);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawString(selected, 375, 75);
                g2.drawString("" + pScore, 375, 125);
                g2.drawString("" + oScore, 375, 175);
            }
        }
    }

    public void getPuz() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String line = "A B 1";
        File f = new File("Word List/" + selected + ".txt");
        int num = 0;
        LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        String lineRead = "";
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        }
        linenum = reader.getLineNumber();
        reader.close();
        try {
            allPuz = new String[linenum];
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            System.out.println("File Opening");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem opening File");
        }
        while (line != null) {
            try {
                line = in.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    allPuz[num] = "" + line;
                    num++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Problem reading data from file");
            }
            if (line != null) {
            }
        }
        try {
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Closing File");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem Closing " + e);
        }
    }

    public void createPuz() throws IOException {
        randomnum = (int) (Math.random() * linenum);
        if (players == 1)
            puz = "" + allPuz[randomnum];
        else if (players == 2)
            puz = cusPuz.getText();
        System.out.println(puz);
        length = puz.length();
        puzle = new char[length];
        hid = new char[length];
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            puzle[x] = (puz.charAt(x));
            if (puzle[x] == ' ') {
                hid[x] = (' ');
                count += 1;
            } else
                hid[x] = ('_');
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent f) {
        if (gameDone == false) {
            String key = "" + f.getKeyChar();
            Boolean rightletter = false;
            wrong = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                if (("" + leter[x]).equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    if (checked[x] == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Already pressed "
                                + leter[x] + ".");
                        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
                            if ((leter[x] == puzle[y])
                                    || (leter2[x] == puzle[y])) {
                                hid[y] = puzle[y];
                                rightletter = true;
                                wrLetter[x] = 1;
                                wrong = false;
                                checked[x] = 1;
                                if (count == length) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                            "You Win");
                                    gameDone = true;
                                    pScore += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (checked[x] == 0) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
                            if ((leter[x] == puzle[y])
                                    || (leter2[x] == puzle[y])) {
                                hid[y] = puzle[y];
                                rightletter = true;
                                wrLetter[x] = 1;
                                count += 1;
                                wrong = false;
                                checked[x] = 1;
                                if (count == length) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                            "You Win");
                                    gameDone = true;
                                    pScore += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    rong = x;
                }
            }
            if (rightletter == false) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                    if (("" + leter[x]).equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                        move++;
                        wrLetter[x] = 2;
                        checked[x] = 1;
                        rong = x;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (wrong == true)
                wrLetter[rong] = 2;
            wrong = true;
            if (move == 7) {
                imageURL2 = cl.getResource("hanger2.png");
                image2 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL2);
            } else if (move >= 8) {
                imageURL2 = cl.getResource("hanger3.png");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Lose");
                oScore += 1;
                gameDone = true;
                pnlBoard.setEnabled(false);
                resetBtn.setEnabled(true);
                image2 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL2);
                for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
                        if ((leter[x] == puzle[y]) || (leter2[x] == puzle[y])) {
                            hid[y] = puzle[y];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                imageURL2 = cl.getResource("hanger.png");
                image2 = toolkit.createImage(imageURL2);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent f) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent f) {
    }
}
```

If any one wants to see the images/files and/or download them to use while checking, I uploaded this code to [Github](https://github.com/Exikle/HangmanOriginal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to focus on the `getPuz()` function to make the work of codesparkle more manageable. :)

### Exceptions handling

The first, high-level problem is the way you use try/catch blocks. Exceptions are not here to get into your way! They're great tools that let you write robust programs and focus on error conditions only where necessary. Writing "Problem opening file" and continuing execution as if nothing had happened is a really bad idea. The truth is that if you can't open that file then your program is useless. So you might as well show the error to your users and quit the program once they acknowledged it. I removed all try/catch blocks from the code since your function already says `throws Exception` and because `getPuz()` is not the place to handle exceptions.

### Declarations

```
public void getPuz() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line = "A B 1";
```

Why "A B 1"? When programming, you optimize for reading: reading your code should be effortles. This is not the case when an arbitrary string shows up like this. Also try avoiding setting anything to `null` when possible. Here this means not declaring the `BufferedReader` right away.

### Line count and better container

```
    File f = new File("Word List/" + selected + ".txt");
    int num = 0;
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
    String lineRead = "";
    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    }
    linenum = reader.getLineNumber();
    reader.close();
```

You're going through a lot of trouble to count the number of lines in the file. The first think a reader thinks when looking at this is "wtf?". This is where good comments can help: you could have written "Count the number of lines in f". But the better thing to do is to actually use a better container for `allPuz`. You could use a `ArrayList` instead which allows you to append new elements without losing performance. This would allow you to change the real reading code:

```
    allPuz = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    System.out.println("File Opening");
```

See, it's simpler to declare `in` here. Also, `allPuz` is a `ArrayList` now, I'll be able to use the `add` method later on.

### Reading lines

```
    while (line != null) {
        line = in.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            allPuz[num] = "" + line;
            num++;
        }
    }
```

There's another way to write this kind of code which avoids you from writing the `null` test twice:

```
    while ((line = in.readline()) != null) {
        allPuz.append(line)
    }

    if (line != null) {
    }
```

### Useless declarations

As codesparkle mentioned for other declaration, this is useless: remove it!

```
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Closing File");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - and good review! But I'd suggest `ArrayList<E>` instead of `Vector<E>` as the latter [is considered outdated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) (it synchronizes each individual operation, which doesn't have any benefits for concurrency but slows down the code. Also, the name `Vector` is misleading).

Comment: @Cygal What is an ArrayList and what does it do? I'm not exactly sure how to implement it due to that lack of knowledge, sorry. And thanks :)

Comment: It's a collection that stores objects, just like the array you used. See [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), [List interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and [List implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) from the official Java tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for sharing your code. Quite frankly, it's a bit of a mess, so let's try to clean it up.

## General Code Issues

Here are a few examples of issues with your code that can easily be corrected. All these issues can be automatically detected by a good IDE such as the free, open-source and excellent [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)<sup>1</sup> *(Analyze->Inspect Code)*.

- You import many classes that you never use. Remove all unnecessary imports, keeping only the ones your code requires. You should also be consistent in your use of `*` wildcards; either use them always or never.
- Why are you suppressing a warning that is not affecting your code? Remove it.

  ```
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  ```
- Why are you declaring but never using `pnl3`, `pnl4`, `pnl5` and `pnl6`? Remove them.
- Why are you declaring the constructor and `main` as `throws Exception` when they don't? Remove. The same goes for `throws IOException` on `createPuz`.
- [Package names in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) are expected to be lower-case,
  so you should change `package Hangman;` to `package hangman;`
- Version logs should be kept in source control, not in the source files (I noticed this in your upload)
- Remove redundant comments that say nothing, such as this one:

  ```
  // Panels where everything is drawn on
  ```
- There's no need to add compare Boolean values with `true` or `false` literals, just use them directly:

  - `if (gameDone == false)` becomes `if (gameDone)`
  - `if (rightletter == false)` becomes `if (!rightletter)`
  - `if (wrong == true)` becomes `if (wrong)`

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> If you download it, be sure to use the new *Darcula* theme.

Comment: this is amazing, just out curiosity do you have like a checklist of things you check throughout the code and if you do, perhaps you could tell me because instead of bringing a fully raw code, i could self check first?

Comment: so i have done all this, as well i also have modified the code using the program you mentioned (pretty cool program) and have created a custom JButton class and shortened the code. I have uploaded the code on Git and here too.